# Undesired sharp edges with smooth shading

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to achieve smooth shading on a model with subsurface. It worked pretty well until recently, now smooth shading works only with edges under certain angle. I don't use the edge split modifier.

**Edit mode:**

[image: model on edit mode]

**Object mode:**

[image: model on object mode]

**Disabling the subsurface mod:**

[image: object without subsurface]

**Joining another object with smooth edges:**

[image: join another smooth object]

You can have a look at my blender 2.8 project here

[image]

Comment: your link doesn't seem to work, could you upload it here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: This is due to autosmooth (mesh properties, normal part). Try to either deactivate it or tune the value (maybe 180°) so that the arm will be smooth and the nails stay sharp.

Comment: @moonboots the link has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big thank to @lemon, you saved me a whole bunch of hours. idk why this was checked, but now it works as before.

You can see by yourself.

[image: Workbench capture]

The option is located there:

[image: Autosmooth mesh option capture]